# Why are my Dynamically Generated Controls not taking an ID value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I'm adding Dynamic text areas to my page and setting names and IDs for them when I Create them but then at run time the controls all have names like ctl01.

I have stepped through the code and am using a recursive FindControl extension but when it gets to the dynamically added textarea it clearly shows that they have the ID that I set them to but their name is "ctl00$MainContent$ctl03"

My findcontrol method fails even though I can clearly see that the ID of the control matches the string I'm searching for. However if I change the search string to "ctl03" (the name value that ASP assigns my control) it works and finds the control fine. This leads me to believe that FindControl actually searches by Name and not ID. Which would be find IF I could set the name of the control, which even though I'm doing explictly ASP is refusing to acknowledge.

CODE:
The Following Method gets called from the "ApplicationForm_PreInit" event

```
   Private Sub AddSupplementalQuestions()
        For Each question In Board.ApplicationXML.<BoardorCommission>.<Questions>.<Question>
            Dim Qdiv As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div")
            Qdiv.Attributes.Add("id", question.@Name.ToString & "div")

            Dim lbl1 As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("Label")
            lbl1.Attributes.Add("id", question.@Name.ToString & "lbl")
            lbl1.InnerHtml = question.<QuestionText>.Value
            Qdiv.Controls.Add(lbl1)

            Dim br2 As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
            Qdiv.Controls.Add(br2)

            Dim tb1 As New HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea
            tb1.Attributes.Add("id", question.@Name.ToString & "tb")
            tb1.Attributes.Add("Textmode", "Multiline")
            tb1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            tb1.Attributes.Add("name", question.@Name.ToString & "tb")
            tb1.Attributes.Add("style", "width:45%; height: 50px;")
            tb1.Attributes.Add("TextMode", "MultiLine")

            Qdiv.Controls.Add(tb1)

            ControlstoAdd.Add(Qdiv)
        Next
    End Sub
```

This is my Recursive FindControl Exstension

```
Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal id As String) As Control
        Dim c As Control = Nothing

        If ctrl.ID = id Then
            c = ctrl
        Else
            For Each childCtrl In ctrl.Controls
                Dim resCtrl As Control = FindControlRecursive(childCtrl, id)
                If resCtrl IsNot Nothing Then c = resCtrl
            Next
        End If

        Return c
End Function
```

Then I'm calling this

```
Dim tb2 = FindControlRecursive(Me, question.@Name.ToString & "tb")
```

which should find the control no problem but it doesn't. And when I view source on the page the control looks like the following

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl03" id="Whatcanyouprovidetb" Textmode="MultiLine" runat="server" style="width:45%; height: 50px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: If you are using JavaScript to get access to those items, yes, the full name is important.  .NET makes the names like that in an attempt to make them unique, and based on how the controls are nested in other controls.  In the code-behind, you will not have to worry about the full name in the rendered HTML, only the id you gave them.

Comment: Why are you instantiating `HtmlControls` in your code-behind and then adding properties to make them behave as ASP.NET server controls? Just make them server controls to start with and inject them into a container control's `Items` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting control `ID` property. Adding `"id"` to their attribute collection leaves `ID` property empty. Then it gets auto-assigned by ASP.NET for the purpose of producing unique html `id`/`name` values. Do:

```
Qdiv.ID = question.@Name.ToString & "div"

lbl1.ID = question.@Name.ToString & "lbl"

tb1.ID = question.@Name.ToString & "tb"
```

You seem to add a number of things to `Attributes` collection that should be set using explicit control properties.